# Laptop Battery is not charging above 59%

Tags: battery, lenovo-laptop, charging

I recently purchased Lenovo G50-80 laptop and installed ubuntu 14.04LTS, when i put my laptop on charge it is getting stuck at 59 and not charging above that. Please provide a solution.

Comment: Some Lenovos have a BIOS setting to save battery life by not charging it fully when primary use is in a dock or otherwise lamost always connected to the mains. So check your BIOS settings.

Comment: If there are no settings configured to restrict charging (either thru OS or BIOS Setup) , then you might actually have a faulty battery out of the box. It seems unusual that such settings would be capping at 59% though. Normally it should be  80 to 90% of full charge. I had a similar issue with my Sony Vaio. The battery would no charge beyond 65%. After showing and proving it to the vendor I got a replacement that worked fine.

Comment: Did the machine come with any OS preinstalled? The most likely scenarios are that the battery has a fault, the OS is unable to read the battery % correctly, or possibly a BIOS bug/feature. It might be worth checking in another OS if you can, seeing if the BIOS reports any information on your battery, or updating the BIOS to see if there are any changes (might require Windows).

Comment: @wurtel there is nothing related to battery settings in the BIOS.

Comment: @Jonno No it is DOS, as you suggested i ll try installing the windows and see for the battery settings.

Comment: I have switched to windows10 and after installing Lenovo one key optimizer and changing the settings  my battery is charging upto 100%.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a SMART Battery feature so the battery keeps is life longer. Check your BIOS Settings for more info on this.

"The thresholds can be adjusted in the Battery Maintenance settings of the Lenovo Power Manager."

Comment: Please provide reference for your quote. Doing so offers validity to your answer.

Comment: I have switched to windows10 and after installing Lenovo one key optimizer and changing the settings, my battery is charging upto 100% now